# Android React - Getting "Requiring unknown module react"

Tags: android, react-native

I keep getting this error when running the app on mobile android device, can anyone help.

The actual error:

```
Error: Requiring unknown module "react". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the package or running "npm install". (index.android.bundle:93)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common error when developing React Native apps

Standing in the project root fgrep -rlo "React" . | grep -v "node_modules" will give you all places where "React" is being called

If this doesn't help you find your issue, there are lots of things you can try but you will have to provide more code

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` in command line at project root directory.

If it still fails, try to run `npm install react --save`